# PyQt4 - How to connect different signals to the same callable, but be able to differntiate where the signal came from and act accordingly

Tags: python, pyqt4

Sorry the title is such a mouth full, but basically what I am trying to do here is that I have 3 buttons, all of them open the QFileDialog for the user to choose a file to use. Since the action is the same, I would like to use the same function for all 3, but depending on which button is pressed, I need to update different QLineEdit to reflect the file path in the GuI. How do I go about achieving that?

```
        #Create the prompt for user to load in the q script to use
        self.qFileTF = QtGui.QLineEdit("Choose the q script file to use")
        self.qFileButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Open")
        self.qFileButton.setFixedSize(100,27)
        self.fileLayout1.addWidget(self.qFileTF)
        self.fileLayout1.addWidget(self.qFileButton)

        #Create the prompt for user to load in the light house file to use
        self.lhFileTF = QtGui.QLineEdit("Choose the light house file to use")
        self.lhButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Open")
        self.lhButton.setFixedSize(100,27)
        self.fileLayout2.addWidget(self.lhFileTF)
        self.fileLayout2.addWidget(self.lhButton)

        #Create the prompt for user to choose to reference an older version of q script
        self.oldQCB = QtGui.QCheckBox("Reference an older version Q script")
        self.oldQTF = QtGui.QLineEdit("Choose the q script file to use")
        self.oldQTF.setEnabled(False)
        self.oldQButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Open")
        self.oldQButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.oldQButton.setFixedSize(100,27)
        self.fileLayout3.addWidget(self.oldQTF)
        self.fileLayout3.addWidget(self.oldQButton) 

        self.connect(self.qFileButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.loadFile)
        self.connect(self.lhButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.loadFile)
        self.connect(self.oldQButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.loadFile)

    def loadFile(self):     
        selFile = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()           

        if self.qFileButton:
            self.qFileTF.setText(selFile)
        elif self.lhFileTF:
            self.lhFileTF.setText(selFile)
        else:
            self.oldQTF.setText(selFile)
```

Comment: If you are going to act differently depending on the signal sender, then why don't you use different methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `sender` method:

```
def loadFile(self):
    selFile = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    if self.sender() == self.qFileButton:
        self.qFileTF.setText(selFile)
    elif self.sender() == self.lhFileTF:
        self.lhFileTF.setText(selFile)
    else:
        self.oldQTF.setText(selFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `QLineEdit` to change as an additionnal parameter to the slot using a lambda function (or a [partial](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function):

```
    def loadFile(lineEdit):
        return lambda: self.loadFile(lineEdit)

    self.qFileButton.clicked.connect(loadFile(self.qFileTF))
    self.lhButton.clicked.connect(loadFile(self.lhFileTF))
    self.oldQButton.clicked.connect(loadFile(self.oldQTF))

def loadFile(self, lineEdit):     
    selFile = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()           
    lineEdit.setText(selFile)
```